How can I remove these pins?
How can I remove these 3/4 pins?



There are a few proven ways to do that:

Push them out from the inside with a suitable instrument (Technic axle, knitting needle, chopstick, screwdriver, etc)
Grab them from the outside with a pair of needle nose pliers or similar tools (wrap the end in duct tape to prevent scratches on the pins)
Slide a half-width liftarm piece over the protruding part, then push any part with a 3.18 mm bar end (also known as minifigure-scale handle) into the round hole. The bar will keep the lips of the pin open, so when you pull on the liftarm, the other end of the pin (that is embedded in the black frame) will have to give.
See also part H of this illustration from the manual of 8868 Air Tech Claw Rig released in 1992, detailing more disassembly methods:


